# InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] error

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When I'm building this model, it shows error :

InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [64 1] [y (sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [64 60]
[[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at C:\Users\dfgdfsgsfg\myfrstml.py:136) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_18192]

Function call stack:
train_function

How can I fix it?

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import yfinance as yf
from collections import deque 
import random
import numpy as np
import time 
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

SEQ_LEN = 60
FUTURE_PERIODO_PREDICT = 3 
EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 64
NAME = f"{SEQ_LEN}-SEQ-{FUTURE_PERIODO_PREDICT}-PRED-{int(time.time())}"

def classify(current,future):
    if float(future)> float(current):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def preprocess_df(df):  
    df=df.drop('future',1)
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if col != "target": 
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)
            
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    sequential_data = []
    prev_days = deque(maxlen=SEQ_LEN)
    
    for i in df.values:  # iterate over the values
        prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])  # store all but the target
        if len(prev_days) == SEQ_LEN:  # make sure we have 60 sequences!
            sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1]])
            
    random.shuffle(sequential_data)
    
    buys=[]
    sells=[]
    
    for seq, target in sequential_data: 
        if target == 0:  
            sells.append([seq, target])  
        elif target == 1: 
            buys.append([seq, target]) 
            
    random.shuffle(buys)
    random.shuffle(sells)
    
    lower = min(len(buys), len(sells))
    
    buys = buys[:lower]
    sells = sells[:lower]
    
    sequential_data = buys+sells
    
    random.shuffle(sequential_data)
        
    X = []
    Y = []
    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        X.append(seq) 
        Y.append(target)
    return np.array(X).astype("float32"), np.array(Y)
    
        

df = yf.Ticker("MSFT").history(period="max").drop(columns=['Dividends','Stock Splits'])

df['future'] = df['Close'].shift(-FUTURE_PERIODO_PREDICT)

df['target'] = list(map(classify, df['Close'], df['future']))



times = sorted(df.index.values)
last_5pct = times[-int(0.05*len(times))]
validation_df = df[(df.index >= last_5pct)]
df = df[(df.index < last_5pct)]

train_x, train_y = preprocess_df(df)
validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_df)



model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2,activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',  
                optimizer =opt, metrics=['accuracy'])


tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f'logs/{NAME}')

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}" 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath,monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) 

# Train model
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=EPOCHS, 
                    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
                    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])



# Score model
score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
# Save model
model.save("models/{}".format(NAME))
```

Comment: set return_sequences=False in the last LSTM cell

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: yes and it didnt worked